# An explanation about "why is the Universe charge neutral"

Tags: particle-physics, cosmology, charge, conservation-laws, universe

I am new at physics. I have a question: What evidence is there that support the statement that the Universe is charge neutral?

Is there anybody explain to me?

Comment: Charge, along with energy, is a Conserved Property. It follows from symmetry requirements, I believe.

Comment: Do you have any proof that it is so? It is mostly neutral, but its total charge is unknown

Comment: Your question's title doesn't match the body. Do you want to know why the universe has zero net charge, or how we know as much?

Comment: @J.G. You're right. I'll change it. Actually, I want to know why is that.

Comment: The conflict is still there after your edit. It sounds like you really ought to edit the body.